# Spacy Entity Linking training - KeyError

Tags: python, spacy, entity-linking

I have seen the question about this here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4723

I am using the new example from: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4789/commits/7b8a18924e3cb1c4630f030a0fc4a09046933c96 (and on spacy's website)

I am still getting the same `KeyError: (14, 17)`. The script says it is compatible with v2.2.3 and that's the version I have. The only thing I have changed are the training examples, nothing else.